# Autocomplete - How can I fire the server-side binding for the datasource after retyping the first few characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im using Ajax binding on a Autocomplete widget.  The binding works fine the first time (at the first load of data), but if I back up over the value, it wont go back to the server again (it won't refresh it's dataSource items).  How can I get the dataSource to refresh if I type a new string?

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("Orders")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color:lightyellow;width:300px;" })
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.Select("selectOrder");
    })
    .Filter("startswith")
    .Placeholder("Select order or enter new one")
    .Filter("startswith")
    .MinLength(3)    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerOrders", "Processing")
    .Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getInputs"))).DataTextField("HouseNo"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provide your input text for the read then you have to set the `ServerFiltering` ([documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete/serverfiltering)) for your datasource to `true` in order to always filter from the server. I'm guessing that is the way that you want to handle it right?
This will always trigger a server filtering though so if you have a lot of data it might be a good idea to set a MinLength for your requests for example 3-4 like this

```
.MinLength(4)
```

This way your datasource will read after the first 4 characters are typed and when you delete a character a dataSource.Read will be triggered too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the `ServerOperation` on the Datasource to true, like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Read(read => read.Action("CustomerOrders", "Processing"))
.ServerOperation(true)
```